# Syntax error when creating a STORED PROCEDURE on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL and I keep getting a syntax error near line 12. I've already attempted to use END CASE; after the CASE WHEN and the same error pops up. Any advice on what the reason for this error could be? I'm using the wampserver MySQL command line.

Here's the code:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE aumento_sueldo()
    BEGIN
        UPDATE activos
        SET sueldo_issste = sueldo_issste*CASE
        CASE WHEN (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(fecha_ingreso)) BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN 1.01
             WHEN (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(fecha_ingreso)) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN 1.05
             WHEN (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(fecha_ingreso)) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN 1.07
             WHEN (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(fecha_ingreso)) >= 40 THEN 1.10
             ELSE 1.00
END |
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have two CASE keywords

Comment: still need to end your statements with `;`, and also use `END`  for the CASE clause (or `END CASE`, it's easy to confuse those)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE aumento_sueldo()
    BEGIN
        UPDATE activos
        SET sueldo_issste = sueldo_issste * CASE my_case 
                                                WHEN (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(fecha_ingreso)) BETWEEN 10 AND 19 THEN 1.01 
                                                WHEN (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(fecha_ingreso)) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN 1.05 
                                                WHEN (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(fecha_ingreso)) BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN 1.07 
                                                WHEN (YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(fecha_ingreso)) >= 40 THEN 1.10 
                                                ELSE 1.00 

                                            END;
END//        
DELIMITER ;
```

[Check here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)  how to use case in store procedure

Comment: too many `;`.  Should only have it after END CASE

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I'm pretty sure it needs the comas . Have you checked the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) ?

Comment: Yes, and I copy/pasted in Mysql 5.7 to be sure. My edits work

Comment: The `END` vs `END CASE` always throws me, but only use `END CASE` if it is a case statement, not in a case expression.

Comment: The semi-colons are also specific to case statement vs expression. The case statement is like an IF statement, and then individual statements have semi-colon. But with the expression (ie. part of a SELECT or UPDATE statement), no semi-colons

Comment: @GarrGodfrey thanks  . Then , I will leave it this way for the `OP`